# 小数以下の桁数チェックを行いたい

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core

https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.2
上記のチュートリアルに従って実装しました。

```
[Column(TypeName = "decimal(18, 2)")]
public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

属性上は、小数以下２桁となっていますが、小数以下を３桁以上入力してもエラーになりません。
（四捨五入されて登録されます）
これは既定の動作でしょうか？

クライアントサイド（jQuery validation）、サーバーサイドにて属性に従った小数以下の桁数チェックを行うにはどのように実装すればよいでしょうか。

Comment: サーバーサイド側について、Stack Overflow 上の関連質問です: [Validate decimal value to 2 decimal places with data annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9558549/5989200) (現状の最も良い回答は kabichan さんの回答と似たものです)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

サーバーサイドなら`RegularExpression`で実装することができます。

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$", ErrorMessage = > "少数以下２桁以上は入力できません"] 

public decimal Price {get; set;}
```

### 結果

> エラーなし 
>   300
>   1.
>   1.0 
>   .5
>   0.25
>
> エラーあり
>   1.250
>   1.555
>   2.7777777

Comment: <del>修正後でも `1.` や `.5` はマッチしません。また、`\.` ではなく `.` になっているので `3x5` みたいなものもマッチしてしまいます。</del>また、これは質問に明確には書かれていませんが、マイナスが付くとマッチしません。

Comment: フランス式だと小数点が `,` になってしまうのですが、そこまでサポートすべきかは場合によりますね……。

Comment: @nekketsuuu 度々ありがとうございます。`\.`が自動的に`.`に変換されて表示されていたようですが`\\.`で入力しましたら`\.`と表示することができましたので訂正致しました。ASP.NETでは`1.`や`.5`はマッチされていると思うのですが、https://regexr.com/　などのツールではマッチしないようです。

Comment: kabichan さん、あれ、ASP.NET も perl 式の正規表現だと思っていたのですが、そうですか、ありがとうございます。エスケープについては引用 (`>`) ではなくコードブロック (`{}`) として装飾するとエスケープしなくて済むはずです。

Comment: @nekketsuuu  確かにコードブロックを使うべきでした。訂正致しました。ありがとうございます。